# Kafka Connect S3 sink - how to utilize no partitioning in s3-sink.properties

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

For legitimate reasons I am looking to dump all Kafka messages into a AWS S3 bucket without partitioning. I have a requirement to use JSON.

My initial thought was to use the [FieldPartitioner](https://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/configuration_options.html) and designate a key/value that is consistent across all topic messages. This would result in all messages ending in the same partition. However, since FieldPartitioner only works with Avro and not JSON, this is not possible.

My current s3-sink.properties replicates Kafka's partitioning stucture:

```
name=s3-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
tasks.max=50
topics=topic_a,topic_b,topic_c
s3.region=us-east-2
s3.bucket.name=datapipeline
s3.part.size=5242880
flush.size=1
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
schema.generator.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
schema.compatibility=NONE
```

Comment: I do understand the benefits of partitioning, but in this use case, partitions create unneeded complexity downstream.

Comment: Would you be able to write your own partitioner?

Comment: @cricket_007 I've never developed in Java, so I'd venture a no on a custom partitioner.

Comment: Are you sure FieldPartitioner only works with Avro? I haven't seen any reference to that in the docs..